# Как сделать что бы при вводе уравнения оно превращалось в числа

Tags: python

У меня есть программа, которая решает уравнения типа `c = k * x + b`, где `c`, `K` и `b` пользователь выбирает сам.
Сейчас этот выбор выглядит примерно вот так:

```
words = "  Выберите c"
for char in words:
    sleep(0.05)
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
c = int(input("\n  "))

words = "  Выберите k"
for char in words:
    sleep(0.05)
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
k = int(input("\n  "))

words = "  Выберите b"
for char in words:
    sleep(0.05)
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
b = int(input("\n  "))
```

Но я бы хотел, чтобы пользователь вводил, например, `10 = 4 * x + 6` и переменные получали значения типа `c = 10, K = 4, b = 6`. Возможно ли сделать что-то подобное?

Comment: А именно в таком порядке или он может и `6 + x*4 = 10` написать, например?

Comment: Порядок не важен

Comment: Ну... Я создал вот такого вот Франкенштейна из сайтов-самоучебников, форумов и чутка того что знал иии... Оно не работает. Дело в том что он берёт числа из списка, НО воспринимает их как символы, то есть как буквы и как следствие их нельзя засунуть в пример, так вот, можно ли как то из таких "Псевдо чисел" сделать нормальные? Вот код:
answer = input ("    Формула: c = k*x+b")
txt = answer

x = txt.split(" ")

test_list = x
 

c, m = [test_list[i] for i in (0, 0)]
k, m = [test_list[i] for i in (2, 2)]
b, m = [test_list[i] for i in (6, 6)] 

print(c, b, k)



x=(c-b)/k
print(x)

Answer (score 3):

Напишу алгоритм в общем виде:

- предварительно убираем из строки ввода все пробелы, чтобы не делать `strip()` каждый раз
- делим через `split` строку по знаку `=`
- в той части, где оказалось число - это берём за `c`
- другую часть делим через тот же `split` по знаку `+`
- в той части, где оказалось число - берём это число как `b`
- делим другую часть по знаку `*`
- в той части, где получилось число - берём её за `k`
- можно ещё проверить, что в другой части получился `x` на всякий случай
- если в конце не остался `x` или если на каком-то этапе не получилось ровно 2 части при разбиении - выдаём ошибку ввода

Comment: Может я туплю, но можно как то присвоить значение переменной из списка, тип дать абстрактной переменной а значение  3-го  элемента списка?

Comment: Извините, я не смог понять вашу мысль (

Answer (score 1):

Можно как-то так

```
import re

for text in '10=4*x+6', '10=10*x', '120 = x*5 +2':
    lst = re.findall(r'(\d+)', text)
    if len(lst) == 3:
        c, k, b = map(int, lst)
        print(f'{text}: c={c}, k={k}, b={b}')
    else:
        print(f'{text}: oшибка ввода выражения!')
```

```
10=4*x+6: c=10, k=4, b=6
10=10*x: oшибка ввода выражения!
120 = x*5 +2: c=120, k=5, b=2
```

Comment: Почему именно `shlex`, а не обыкновенный `split`? Разве получится по-другому?

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм с использованием [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html):

1. Определить переменную ***x***;
2. Ввести уравнение;
3. Разбить на левую и правую части по знаку равенства;
4. Преобразовать части уравнения в выражения `sympy`;
5. Создать уравнение;
6. Решить уравнение.

Код:

```
import sympy


x = sympy.Symbol('x', real=True)
symbols = {'x': x}

while True:
    print()
    eq = input('equation: ')
    lhs, rhs = (sympy.sympify(s, locals=symbols) for s in eq.split('='))
    print(f'{x}:', sympy.solveset(sympy.Eq(lhs, rhs), x))
```

> ```
> $ python solve.py
>
> equation: 10 = 4 * x + 6
> x: {1}
>
> equation: x^2 = 4
> x: {-2, 2}
>
> equation: x^2 + 4*x + 15 = 0
> x: {-2 - sqrt(11)*I, -2 + sqrt(11)*I}
>
> equation: sin(x) = cos(x)
> x: Union(ImageSet(Lambda(_n, 2*_n*pi + 5*pi/4), Integers), ImageSet(Lambda(_n, 2*_n*pi + pi/4), Integers))
> ```